# Can't connect to neo4j via Browser, bolt port changed in neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-bolt, neo4j-browser

I have used neo4j until now with a previous database. I now created a new database and I try to open neo4j browser and suddenly, I find:

> BoltConnectionError: No connection found, did you connect to Neo4j?

Seeing logs of my database, I see :

> 018-12-20 12:56:17.381+0000 WARN  Server thread metrics not available
>   (missing neo4j.server.threads.jetty.all) 2018-12-20 12:56:17.385+0000
>   WARN  Server thread metrics not available (missing
>   neo4j.server.threads.jetty.idle)

I also noticed that the bolt port of my neo4j browser changed from (localhost) 7687 to 11004. I can however open my database on my internet browser with 7687 port. But, I cannot access my favourited cypher scripts. Hence, I would prefer to connect to my graph db through neo4j browser. Any idea on how this issue can be solved? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Bolt port is changed whenever the current port(7687) is used by another process(another instance of neo4j).

You can open the database in your internet browser on port 7687 because there are multiple instances, and you're accessing another instance not the current one.

To access the correct database instance use the current port(11004 in this case). Looks like a port in changed but Neo4j is not running, you need to start/restart the neo4j.

You can check if the neo4j is running or not from cmd(admin mode)
using these commands:

> neo4j status
>
> netstat -ano | findstr :11004

Replace 11004 if the port is different.